# MYSQL query for combining data of two tables sharing Foreign key from a third table

Tags: mysql, union, foreign-key-relationship

I am trying to combine the data from two tables sales & purchase in one table. Both Sales & Purchase table shares foreign key from third table store.

What is the best way to construct the query to get the results exactly as in results tables, Preferably(if possible) without using sub-query, as I need to create a view of the query result and MYSQL doesn't allow create view on query using sub-query.

I have tried select with union but not getting the result as expected.

[underlying tables & query result](http://mywebsolutions.co.in/images/mysql-query-question.png)

Answer (score 0):

The following query(not tested) should give the resultset you want :

```
SELECT store_name AS store, MONTH(sales.date) AS month, SUM(sales.sales) AS sales, SUM(purchase.purchase) AS purchase
FROM store 
JOIN sales ON store.store_id = sales.store_id
JOIN purchase ON store.store_id = purchase.store_id
GROUP BY store.store_id,MONTH(sales.date), MONTH(purchase.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to get that expected result without subquery as you need to group by month and store from two different tables, both possibly having many rows in each group and joining them together before grouping would multiply rows. Even more, you need to do full outer join of these results which in mysql is not supported and you have to emulate it by union of two opposite left joins. So basically with this table schema you have to use a query that is quite complex and looks more like an academic problem than real life example.

```
( SELECT st.store_name, s.month,
          COALESCE( s.salestotal, 0 ) as salestotal, 
          COALESCE( p.purchasetotal, 0 ) as purchasetotal
FROM 
  store st
  JOIN
    ( SELECT store_id, SUM(sales) as salestotal, 
             DATE_FORMAT( date, '%b %Y' ) as month
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY store_id, month ) s
  ON st.store_id = s.store_id
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT store_id, SUM(purchase) as purchasetotal, 
      DATE_FORMAT( date, '%b %Y' ) as month
      FROM purchase
      GROUP BY store_id, month ) p
  ON p.store_id = s.store_id AND p.month = s.month )
UNION
( SELECT st.store_name, p.month,
          COALESCE( s.salestotal, 0 ) as salestotal, 
          COALESCE( p.purchasetotal, 0 ) as purchasetotal
FROM
  store st
JOIN
  ( SELECT store_id, SUM(purchase) as purchasetotal, 
           DATE_FORMAT( date, '%b %Y' ) as month
    FROM purchase
    GROUP BY store_id, month ) p
ON st.store_id = p.store_id
LEFT JOIN 
  ( SELECT store_id, SUM(sales) as salestotal, 
    DATE_FORMAT( date, '%b %Y' ) as month
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY store_id, month ) s
ON
  p.store_id = s.store_id AND p.month = s.month )
ORDER BY month, store_name
```

Comment: The query is not working for me. BTW is there any other way like creating a new table from these existing tables to get the result from there

Comment: Please be more specific about how exactly it is not working for you. If you see any error message write that message here, if it gives different results than you expect post example data and what you should get and so on. Also make sure that you copy full query as it doesn't fit in the window and you have to scroll down to see all of it.